# getBytes not hitting .OnSuccss or .OnFailure listeners within a firebase .OnDataChange

Tags: android, arrays, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I am running an `addValueEventListener` to my Firebase database in a method that runs `onClick` of a button. it retrieves the datasnapshot with a user's data, and then it runs through a for loop that assigns variables to the data points so that they can be saved into the sqlite db. the final step is to check if there is a firebaseStorage url indicating there is a saved image as part of the user's data for a given 'hole', and if so, it must be translated to a byte array. if there isn't one, the app defines the byte array as null and then in both instances, the app should then .put the data into the db.

What I'm finding is that the for loop seems to be running erratically, i.e. not finishing it's process in order. additionally, in most cases, even though there is clearly data in the data snapshot, it is not being saved to the variable 90% of the time. finally, in some cases, though there is a greenURL, the app doesn't either the `.onSuccess` or the `.onFailure` listeners.

it feels like it's a timing problem associated with the fact that `onDataChange` is asynchronous. I attempted to design it so that it would not move on until the process completed, but perhaps I'm mistaken. here is my code:

```
String  holeNumbers[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"};
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String selectedCourse = preferences.getString("selectedCourse","");
myDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    myDb.child("UserNotesData").child("Users").child(uid).child(selectedCourse).child(selectedNotes).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for  (String x:holeNumbers) {
              String hole = "Hole"+x ;
              String holeNumberNotes = x;

              System.out.println("Hole at beginning of DownloadUserNotesData for loop: "+ x);
              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("ApproachIdealMiss").getValue() != null) {
                  approachIdealMiss = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("ApproachIdealMiss").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  approachIdealMiss = "";
              }


              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("ApproachNotes").getValue() != null) {
                  approachNotes = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("ApproachNotes").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  approachNotes = "";
              }
              String greenImageURL;
              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("GreenImageURL").getValue() != null) {
                  greenImageURL =  dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("GreenImageURL").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  greenImageURL = "N/A";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("GreenNotes").getValue() != null) {
                  greenNotes = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("GreenNotes").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  greenNotes = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("TeeIdealMiss").getValue() != null) {
                  teeIdealMiss = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("TeeIdealMiss").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  teeIdealMiss = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("TeeNotes").getValue() != null) {
                  teeNotes = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("TeeNotes").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  teeNotes = "";
              }
              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("TeeShot").getValue() != null) {
                  teeShot = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("TeeShot").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  teeShot = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone1X").getValue() != null) {
                  goZone1X = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone1X").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  goZone1X = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone1Y").getValue() != null) {
                  goZone1Y = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone1Y").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  goZone1Y = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone2X").getValue() != null) {
                  goZone2X = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone2X").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  goZone2X = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone2Y").getValue() != null) {
                  goZone2Y = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("goZone2Y").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  goZone2Y = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone1X").getValue() != null) {
                  noZone1X = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone1X").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  noZone1X = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone1Y").getValue() != null) {
                  noZone1Y = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone1Y").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  noZone1Y = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone2X").getValue() != null) {
                  noZone2X = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone2X").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  noZone2X = "";
              }

              if (dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone2Y").getValue() != null) {
                  noZone2Y = dataSnapshot.child(hole).child("noZone2Y").getValue().toString();
              } else {
                  noZone2Y = "";
              }

              if(!greenImageURL.equals("N/A")) {
              StorageReference greenStorageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(greenImageURL);
              final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
              greenStorageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

                      helperDB.insertUserNotesData(x, approachIdealMiss, approachNotes, greenImageURL, bytes,
                              greenNotes, teeIdealMiss, teeNotes, teeShot, goZone1X, goZone1Y, goZone2X, goZone2Y, noZone1X, noZone1Y, noZone2X, noZone2Y);
                      System.out.println("(greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: " + x);
                      System.out.println("(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: " + approachNotes);


                  }
              })
              .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                      // Handle any errors
                      System.out.println("(greenImage was not blank but failed to be changed to bytes) hole# to be written in db is: "+ x);
                  }
              }); }
              else {



                  byte[] emptyByte = new byte[0];
                  helperDB.insertUserNotesData(x, approachIdealMiss, approachNotes, greenImageURL, emptyByte,
                          greenNotes, teeIdealMiss, teeNotes, teeShot, goZone1X, goZone1Y, goZone2X, goZone2Y, noZone1X, noZone1Y, noZone2X, noZone2Y);
                  System.out.println("(greenImageBlank) hole# to be written in db is: "+ x);
                  System.out.println("(greenImageBlank) TeeNotes to be written in db are: "+approachNotes);

              }



            }

            loadingPercent = loadingPercent + 30;
            loadingProgressBar.setProgress(loadingPercent, true);
            System.out.println("loadingProgress at DownloadUserNotesData: " + loadingPercent.toString());

            if (loadingPercent==100) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (courseSelect.this, PlayNav.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

here is the relevant(ish) print out of console, that I attempted to use to help debug:

```
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7805780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa78039e0)
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 2
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 3
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 1
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 6
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 11
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 8
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 12
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 10
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 14
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
W/Google Maps Android API: Deprecation notice: In a future release,     indoor will no longer be supported on satellite, hybrid or terrain type maps. Even where indoor is not supported, isIndoorEnabled() will continue to return the value that has been set via setIndoorEnabled(), as it does now. By default, setIndoorEnabled is 'true'. The API release notes (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases) will let you know when indoor support becomes unavailable on those map types.
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is: 13
(greenImageSuccess) TeeNotes to be written in db are: 
I/System.out: (greenImageSuccess) hole# to be written in db is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was two fold.

the first thing I did was I put the `loading percent` within the for loop, so that it would only run the intent upon completing each item in the array. the second thing I did was to place all my variables within the for loop, instead of creating them at the class level. this ensured that all the variables were being set correctly by the datasnapshot and that the app was not moving on to the next activity without completely finishing the for loop out.